# Manually start plone 6 instance inside docker container

Tags: docker, plone

Based on example [here](https://6.docs.plone.org/install/containers/images/backend.html) I added `entrypoint: sh -c 'tail -f /dev/null'`:

```
version: "3"
services:

  backend:
    image: plone/plone-backend:6.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      ZEO_ADDRESS: zeo:8100
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - zeo
    entrypoint: sh -c 'tail -f /dev/null'

  zeo:
    image: plone/plone-zeo:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - data:/data
    ports:
    - "8100:8100"

volumes:
  data: {}
```

I started the app using `docker-compose up` as usual, then I run `docker-compose exec backend bash`. Now I can't find a way to start the instance. I expect something like: `bin/instace fg`.

I tried this a lot with no success. Not working with `build: .`, not working with a new `Dockerfile` based on `plone/plone-backend:6.0` + `buildout.cfg`, etc. I feel it should be simple, but just can't figure it out.

I found this: https://community.plone.org/t/interactive-shell-for-debugging-with-plone-6-docker-compose-the-wsgi-equivalent-of-bin-instance-debug/16370

but in my case I don't want a debug mode in this way. My goal is to edit with vim some files from eggs, to add some pdb then I want to start the instance in foreground mode, in order to investigate how some functionalities are working. I do this a lot in Plone 4. How can I do this in Plone 6?

Comment: If you're using a prebuilt image, it seems unusual to override its entrypoint to force the container to do nothing.  What happens normally without this `entrypoint:` line?  If you don't want the container to do anything, can you just delete it from the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: @DavidMaze, without entrypoint set, Plone 6 backend is starting and I can access it from my http://localhost:8080/. I need plone-backend but I want to start it from the container using a `./bin/instance fg` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A solution** (but see the UPDATED one)

```
version: "3"
services:

  backend:
    image: plone/plone-backend:6.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      ZEO_ADDRESS: zeo:8100
      SECURITY_POLICY_IMPLEMENTATION: "C"
      VERBOSE_SECURITY: "off"
      DEFAULT_ZPUBLISHER_ENCODING: "utf-8"
      DEBUG_MODE: "off"
      ZODB_CACHE_SIZE: "50000"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    command: cat
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - zeo

  zeo:
    image: plone/plone-zeo:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - data:/data
    ports:
    - "8100:8100"

volumes:
  data: {}
```

Go into container with:

`$ docker-compose exec backend bash`

Then run:

`$ gosu plone /app/bin/runwsgi -v etc/zope.ini config_file=zope.conf`

This will start the instance in fg mode. (http://0.0.0.0:8080/)

I found this here: https://github.com/plone/plone-backend/issues/64#issuecomment-1211912408

**UPDATE (better solution):**

You can copy this entire code into your docker-compose.yml and you will have the instructions as comments.

```
# CREATE PROJECT
# $ mkdir plone6
# $ cd plone6
# $ vim docker-compose.yml
#   Copy example from
#   https://6.docs.plone.org/install/containers/images/backend.html#example
#     Update: - data:/data
#       with: - ./data:/data
#
# START PLONE
# Stop all docker containers:
# $ docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
# $ docker-compose build
# $ sudo chown -R 500 data/
# $ docker-compose up
#
# ENTER THE BACKEND CONTAINER 
# $ docker-compose exec backend bash
#
# INSTALL VIM INTO CONTAINER
# $ apt update
# $ apt install vim
#
# FIND THE PACKAGES, EDIT (example plone.restapi)
# $ ./bin/python
# >>> import plone.restapi
# >>> plone.restapi.__file__
# '/app/lib/python3.11/site-packages/plone/restapi/__init__.py'
# >>> exit()
# $ vim /app/lib/python3.11/site-packages/plone/restapi/__init__.py
# To add a breakpoint write: import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
#
# START INSTANCE IN FG MODE
# In docker-compose.yml add for backend:
    # tty: true
    # stdin_open: true
    # command: cat
# docker-compose up
# docker-compose exec backend bash
# ./docker-entrypoint.sh
# set
# ./docker-entrypoint.sh start
version: "3"
services:

  backend:
    image: plone/plone-backend:6.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      ZEO_ADDRESS: zeo:8100
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    command: cat
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - zeo

  zeo:
    image: plone/plone-zeo:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    ports:
    - "8100:8100"

volumes:
  data: {}
```